# Determining what radiobutton was selected tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how to use tkinter radio-buttons properly.

I have used this question as a guideline: [Radio button values in Python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660342/radio-button-values-in-python-tkinter)

For some reason I can't figure out how to return a variable that is indicative of what the user selected.

Code:

```
 def quit_loop():
    global selection
    selection = option.get()
    root.quit()
    return selection



def createWindow():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry=('400x400')
    option = StringVar()
    option.set('none')
    R1 = Radiobutton(root, text='Compile', value = 'Compile', var=option)
    R2 = Radiobutton(root, text='Create', value = 'Create', var=option)
    button = Button(root, text='ok', command=quit_loop)
    R1.pack()
    R2.pack()
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

when I call `createWindow()` I would expect the radio-button box to pop up, and after making my selection and pressing 'ok' I expected it to return me a variable `selection` which relates to the selected button. Any advice? Tkinter stuff is particularly challenging to me because it seems so temperamental.

Comment: Where would you expect the value to be returned *to*?  You aren't calling `quit_loop()` yourself, you have no access to its return value.  You need to do whatever needs to be done with that value from within the function.

Comment: @jasonharper this is where I am confused and have no clue what to do.. The link I posted had it set up the exact same way so I am confused. I assumed when the button was pressed it would then call the `quit_loop()` function which would return the value of what was selected

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `option` global if you want to access outside of `createWindow`

Here's an example of your code that will print out the value of the selected radiobutton and then quit when you click the button. I simply had to declare `root` and `options` as global:

```
from tkinter import *

def quit_loop():
    global selection
    selection = option.get()
    root.quit()
    return selection

def createWindow():
    global option, root
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry=('400x400')
    option = StringVar()
    option.set('none')
    R1 = Radiobutton(root, text='Compile', value = 'Compile', var=option)
    R2 = Radiobutton(root, text='Create', value = 'Create', var=option)
    button = Button(root, text='ok', command=quit_loop)
    R1.pack()
    R2.pack()
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()

createWindow()
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know one needs to do two things to communicate with tkinter 
widgets: pass a variable, and pass a command. When user interacts with 
widgets, tkinter will do two things: update value of variable and call the 
function passed in as `command`. It is up to us to access the value of the 
variable inside the command function.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar, Radiobutton

def handle_radio():
    print(option.get())

root = tk.Tk()

option = StringVar()
option.set('none')
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text='Compile', value = 'Compile', var=option, command=handle_radio)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text='Create', value = 'Create', var=option, comman=handle_radio)

R1.pack()
R2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The code prints 'Create' and 'Compile' when user selects the appropriate 
radio option.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Prasanth