# How to create an option menu in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

How can I make an option field in Tkinter?

For example, in HTML it is this:

```
<select>
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Method 1: OptionMenu

The first method is to use `OptionMenu` from `tkinter`. You will have to create a list containing all your desired options. Then you need to have a `variable` that  holds the information regarding *which button is currently selected.*

**Useful resource:** [How can I create a dropdown menu from a List in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441885/how-can-i-create-a-dropdown-menu-from-a-list-in-tkinter)

**Sample code:**

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

OPTIONS = [
"Option 1",
"Option 2",
"Option 3"
] #etc

variable = StringVar()
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image]

## Method 2: Radiobutton

You can use `Radiobutton` in tkinter to have options.

The arguments that you need to pass in are the `window` which is `root`, the `text` to be displayed in the option button, a `shared variable` which holds the information regarding *which button is currently selected*, and unique `value` to distinguish this radio button.

**Note:** each radio button should have a different unique `value` otherwise more than one radio button will get selected.

**Parameters to be passed in:**

```
button = Radiobutton(root, text="Name on Button", variable = “shared variable”, value = “values of each button”)
```

***Useful resources regarding `Radiobutton`*** -

1. [Radio button values in Python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660342/radio-button-values-in-python-tkinter)
2. [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radiobutton-in-tkinter-python/#:~:text=The%20Radiobutton%20is%20a%20standard,calls%20that%20function%20or%20method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radiobutton-in-tkinter-python/#:%7E:text=The%20Radiobutton%20is%20a%20standard,calls%20that%20function%20or%20method).

**Sample code:**

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

payment_method_label=Label(root, text="Select Payment Method:")

payment_method = StringVar()
payment_method.set("card")

cards = Radiobutton(root, text="Debit/Credit Card", variable=payment_method, value="card").pack(anchor=tk.W)
wallet = Radiobutton(root, text="Payment Wallet", variable=payment_method, value="wallet").pack(anchor=tk.W)
netbanking = Radiobutton(root, text="Net Banking", variable=payment_method, value="net banking").pack(anchor=tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image]