# Closing a second Tkinter window doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Imagine the following very simple example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tempFunctions import *

startingWin = Tk()

button = Button(startingWin, text="Open Other Win", command=lambda: openSecondWin()).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=30)

startingWin.mainloop()
```

The output is simply as following:

[image]

No if I click on the button, I open the second Win like:

[image]

The second window has the following code in tempFunctions.py:

```
from tkinter import *

def openSecondWin():

    secondWin = Tk()

    cancelButton = Button(secondWin, text="Cancel", command=secondWin.quit).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=30)

    secondWin.mainloop()
```

I expect that when I press cancel, the secondWin should close. That doesn't happen. What I get is that when I click cancel, the second Win doesn't close. However, if click twice both windows (startingWin and secondWin) close together. Why?

***Is there a logical explanation for this?*** **Thanks!**

### UPDATE:

Trying with binding results in the same problem.

Also making the second win as Toplevel doesn't help.

Comment: @downvoter, I know that the question is silly. But I can't find an explanation for this. I would say sharing your knowledge helps more than down voting. Thanks!

Comment: You should never create more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, everyone but the first needs to be an instance of `Toplevel`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I've tried Toplevel for the second win instead of Tk, but I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `quit()`. However, in case of multiple windows, one should use `destroy()` according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307464/what-is-the-difference-between-root-destroy-and-root-quit). That solved my problem.