# Close button tkinter after pressing button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a button that works perfectly (not entire code here) but I want that once you press the 'Save' button, the window disappear. Someone knows how to do it?

```
root2 = tk.Tk()
root2.geometry('200x100') 
save_button = tk.Button(root2)
save_button.configure(text='Save', command=lambda: ask_parameter(ents1))
save_button.pack()
root2.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `master.quit()` method!
Example Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()
        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Push me!", command=self.closeScreen)
        self.button.pack()

    def closeScreen(self):
        # In your case, you need "root2.quit"
        self.master.quit()

test = Test()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the extremely limited snippet of code in your question: I would suggest it doing by defining a function to call that does something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def ask_and_close(root, ents):
    ask_parameter(ents)
    root.destroy()

ents1 = "something"
root2 = tk.Tk()
root2.geometry('200x100')
save_button = tk.Button(root2)
save_button.configure(text='Save', command=lambda: ask_and_close(root2, ents1))
save_button.pack()
root2.mainloop()
```

Note: If you're creating multiple windows, I wouild suggest using [`tk.Toplevel()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) instead of calling `tk.TK()` more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `destroy()` method as used here https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program.

One of the easy ways to invoke the `destroy` method in your code is this;

```
def ask_parameter_and_destroy(ents1):
    ask_parameter(ents1)
    root2.destroy()

root2 = tk.Tk()
root2.geometry('200x100') 
save_button = tk.Button(root2)
save_button.configure(text='Save', command=lambda: ask_parameter_and_destroy(ents1))
save_button.pack()
root2.mainloop()
```

You can read about differences between `destroy()` and previously proposed `quit()` methods on the following page: [What is the difference between root.destroy() and root.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307464/what-is-the-difference-between-root-destroy-and-root-quit).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a dialog for saving a file, you might be interested in `tkinter.filedialog` library, which has ready made dialog boxes for handling file saving.