# Difference between .quit and .destroy on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What is the difference between .quit and .destroy on Tkinter, they seem to do the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between root.destroy() and root.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307464/what-is-the-difference-between-root-destroy-and-root-quit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.quit()` causes `mainloop` to exit, but doesn't directly cause any widgets to be destroyed. However, if there's no code after calling `mainloop` then the script exits, and all widgets will be destroyed.

`.destroy()` will destroy a widget. If you destroy the root window then all other widgets will be destroyed and `mainloop` will stop.