# Tkinter Entry textvariable not working after call to filedialog.askopenfilename

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to sometimes show a dialog in my application. I destroy and quit Tkinter (the toplevel widget) after the dialog got closed, since I don't know if another dialog will be opened later. However, if I call `open_simple_value_dialog` after `open_file_dialog`, `open_simple_value_dialog` does show an empty input field instead of the default value. If the value is changed and confirmed (click on `Ok` button), the result returned by the dialog is still the default value. `open_simple_value_dialog` does work as expected (shows default value and returns entered value) if `open_file_dialog` is not called before it. How to fix this issue?

```py
def open_file_dialog():
    from tkinter import Tk, filedialog

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select input file')
    root.quit()
    return file_name


def open_simple_value_dialog(default_input_value):
    from tkinter import Tk, IntVar, StringVar, Label, Entry, Button

    root = Tk()

    if isinstance(default_input_value, str):
        input_variable = StringVar()
    elif isinstance(default_input_value, int):
        input_variable = IntVar()
    else:
        raise ValueError('expected string or integer as default input value')
    input_variable.set(default_input_value)
    result = None

    def close_dialog():
        nonlocal root
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()

    def on_ok():
        nonlocal result
        result = input_variable.get()
        close_dialog()

    Label(root, text='enter something').pack()
    Entry(root, textvariable=input_variable).pack()
    Button(root, text='Ok', command=on_ok).pack()
    Button(root, text='Cancel', command=close_dialog).pack()
    root.mainloop()
    return result


def main():
    print(open_file_dialog())
    print(open_simple_value_dialog('text'))
    value = open_simple_value_dialog(0)
    if isinstance(value, int):
        print(value)
    else:
        print('Dialog has been canceled')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Use `root.destroy()` instead of `root.quit()` inside `open_file_dialog()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, that fixes the issue. If you create an answer, I can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `root.quit()` inside `open_file_dialog()`, it just terminates the tkinter `.mainloop()`, but not the underlying TCL interpreter and tkinter widgets (see explanation in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307464/what-is-the-difference-between-root-destroy-and-root-quit)).  So there is still issue on multiple instances of `Tk()` when `open_simple_value_dialog()` is executed.

You need to use `root.destroy()` inside `open_file_dialog()` instead.