# Tkinter GUI's freezing while code is running

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, multiprocessing

I've an instagram bot with GUI's. There is two class with different .py files. I start the functions with GUI's with no problem but since the functions takes long time and until not completed GUI's are freezing. Therefore i cannot click the stop button thats my problem. I tried using threads it leads to not freezing but i cannot stop it. Therefore i need help I return the beginning. What is the easiest way to prevent freezing?

These are brief GUI's code

```
def send_requests(self):
    username = self.username_entry2.get()
    self.bot.send_requests_following(username)

def stop_bot(self):
    self.bot.stop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.on_closing)
    root.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

This is my bot function on other class.

```
    def send_requests_following(self,profile):
```

I really don't know what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried root.quit() ? Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307464/what-is-the-difference-between-root-destroy-and-root-quit

Comment: i tried but didn't work. :/

Comment: The `root.mainloop()` should be at the  bottom

Comment: again it didn'T work :/

Comment: Any function in a GUI that needs to run a long time needs to be in a thread.  Show us your thread attempt.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding a loop then creating an instance of `thread.Events()`. Adding a `is_set()` and if it’s true break the loop. Using `.set()` to terminate the thread by setting `is_set()` to true. Another approach is using the multiprocessing module. Then using `.terminate()` to stop the thread.

Comment: I tried with thread and it works but i cannot stop it i created a loop and i used .set() but it didn't work :/

Comment: Can you post a minimum example of the code showing you using .set()?