# can't get values from variable in tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
app=Tk()
age=IntVar()
name=StringVar()
id=IntVar()
def add_user():
    app1=Tk()
    L1 = Message(app1,text="Name")
    L1.pack( side = LEFT)
    E1 = Entry(app1,textvariable=name)
    E1.pack()
    L2 = Message(app1,text="\nAge")
    L2.pack( side = LEFT)
    E2 = Spinbox(app1,from_=1,to_=100,textvariable=age)
    E2.pack()
    l3=Message(app1,text="\nId")
    l3.pack()
    e3=Spinbox(app1,from_=1,to_=100,textvariable=id)
    e3.pack()
    b5=Button(app1,text="submit",command=app1.destroy)
    b5.pack()
    app1.mainloop()
    print age.get(),name.get(),id.get()
    return

b1=Button(app,command=add_user,relief=RIDGE,text="add patient details")
b1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
app.mainloop()
```

the print statement doesn't print the correct values,it always prints the default values.I don't understand where I made a mistake

Comment: Works fine when you make the "dialog" top-level. Probably a problem with how you start two Tk instances. Also note how the output is only printed after the _main_ window is closed.

Comment: yeah thanks just realized that I need to print after closing the main window

Comment: Still strange... you should investigate how to properly open a modal dialogue in Tkinter (not sure how right now, either).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't get the values is that the widgets have been destroyed once `mainloop` has exited.

The bigger problem in your code is that you are creating two instances of `Tk`. Tkinter isn't designed to work that way. A proper Tkinter program creates exactly one instance of `Tk`, and exits when that one instance is destroyed. If you want to create more than one window, the second and subsequent windows need to be instances of [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm).

You might find the answer to this question useful: [Correct way to implement a custom popup tkinter dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10057672/7432)