# Tkinter FileTypes (askopenfilename), how to add Folder option

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can you add an option so that you can select a folder or directory instead of a file extension type. For example, I want two options, a zip and a folder FileTypes option in my askopenfilename statement. I'd put filetypes=[('Zip File', '*.zip'), for a Zip file but what do I put for an actual directory or folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `filedialog.askdirectory()`:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

For Python 2 use `tkFileDialog.askdirectory()`.

Comment: @import_os: There are many examples of using it [here](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/16883/tkFileDialog.askdirectory).

Comment: But does this let you select zip files too? As the OP said "I want two options, a zip and a folder FileTypes option"

Comment: @abccd: As far as I know, there's nothing built-in that would do that—you'd need to create your dialog function to do that—which isn't that difficult, see this [documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20161102024158/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm).

Comment: @import_os: Also see [**_Correct way to implement a custom popup tkinter dialog box_**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057672/correct-way-to-implement-a-custom-popup-tkinter-dialog-box).

Comment: I knew about this but wanted a work around with askopenfilename. Oh well, I'll just implement a way to make it where I can tell the user if they chose an invalid file type. Thanks.