# How to put a returned value of a function into a variable using python?

Tags: python, tkinter

As I tried to express in the topic what I want is whenever the OK button is clicked from the pop up window, I want it to be stored in the variable host.

It is easy to print it but what I want is to put it inside my variable host, is there a way?

```
from tkinter import *
    class dialog():
        def __init__(self,master,question):
            root=Toplevel(master)
            root.geometry('200x84+20+15')
            root.overrideredirect(True)
            root.config(background='grey')
            quetsion=question.capitalize()
            Label(root,text=quetsion,bg='grey',fg='white',justify='center').grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=N+W,padx=50)
            text=StringVar()
            Entry(root,textvariable=text,bg='grey',fg='white',justify='center',width=30).grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=N+W,padx=8,pady=5)
            Button(root,text='Ok',bg='grey',fg='white',width=11,justify='center',command=lambda:self.ok(text.get())).grid(column=0,row=2,sticky=N+W,padx=8,pady=5)
            Button(root,text='Cancle',bg='grey',fg='white',width=11,justify='center',command=lambda:self.close(root)).grid(column=0,row=2,sticky=N+W,pady=5,padx=105)
        def ok(self,value):#the OK function for the OK button
            return value #the value to be put inside host when the OK button is clicked 
        def close(self,master):
            master.destroy()

    win=Tk()
    win.geometry('0x0+0+0')
    host=dialog(win,'What is your name')
    print(host)
    win.mainloop()
```

And also how does a tkinter simple dialogue do it? I tried to read the source code but it is not clear.

Comment: This is not possible. You can't get a result from a dialog before you've started the mainloop.

Comment: If that is so how does a simple dialogue of tkinter work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to implement a custom popup tkinter dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057672/correct-way-to-implement-a-custom-popup-tkinter-dialog-box)

Comment: Hi Hilea, I have updated my answer to provide a way to use your global variable `host` after you have closed your `dialog()` tkinter class window. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That exactly was what I wanted thank you for the help and the explanation.

Comment: Got question. What if I want to have more than one dialogue box, do I have to start a new sizeless window again, for example if I also want to ask age and display it along Side name do I have to do the same process again or would there  be a shorter approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you need to change for it to work properly.

First we need to fix some issues with the class.

You are going to need to use class attributes here and you need to assign at least the entry field and the label as a class attribute in order to be able to update the labels text. You will also need to set the `grid()` location after you create the button or else when you try to use `get()` on the entry field or try to update the label you will just get `None` returned from the geometry manager.

You do not need string var here as you are using a button to call a method to update the text you can just use `get()` on the entry field.

We can also reference master to a class attribute like this:

`self.root = master`

This will allow us to interact with the self.root attribute in any method without having to pass it as an argument.

So for your `close()` method you can do `self.root.destroy()` instead and it will work fine.

That being said you should make sure you create unique names that will not override what is already a method in python. For example `close` is already used in python for closing an open file. So instead of naming your method `close()` you should do something like `close_app()` this will prevent any problems down the road if you start using pythons close method.

In a class you need to make sure that anything that needs to be called on more than once or in a method after the program has initialized that you have assigned it to a class attribute with `self.`

Now that we have cleaned up the class a bit lets fix your issue with updating `host` and then printing it.

Because you can only have one tkinter application running at one time. You can create one window ( your dialog class ) to update a global variable ( your `host` variable ) and then close itself out. Once `dialog()` has closed the rest of the python program will run that comes after `mainloop()` so We can write up some code to use the value of `host` or even another tkinter app.

Take a look at the below code:

```
from tkinter import *


class dialog():
    def __init__(self, master, question):
        # removed Toplevel() because you code did not show a root window 
        # so top level is not needed here.
        # If you would like this to be a Toplevel called from another class
        # Then you can change self.root = master back to self.root = Toplevel(master)
        self.root = master
        self.root.geometry('200x84+20+15')
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)
        self.root.config(background='grey')
        quetsion=question.capitalize()
        self.lbl1 = Label(self.root, text=quetsion, bg='grey', fg='white', justify='center')
        self.lbl1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=N+W,padx=50)

        self.entry1 = Entry(self.root, bg='grey', fg='white', justify='center', width=30)
        self.entry1.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=N+W,padx=8,pady=5)

        Button(self.root, text='Ok', bg='grey', fg='white', width=11, justify='center',
               command=lambda:self.ok(self.entry1.get())).grid(column=0,row=2,sticky=N+W,padx=8,pady=5)

        Button(self.root, text='Cancel', bg='grey', fg='white', width=11, justify='center',
               command=lambda:self.close_app()).grid(column=0,row=2,sticky=N+W,pady=5,padx=105)

    def ok(self, value):
        global host
        if self.entry1.get() != "":
            host = self.entry1.get()
            self.root.destroy()

    def close_app(self):
        self.root.destroy()


win=Tk()
win.geometry('0x0+0+0')
host = ""
dialog(win,'What is your name')
win.mainloop()

win = Tk()
Label(win, text="The host name is {}".format(host)).pack()
Button(win, text="Close", command = lambda: win.destroy()).pack()
win.mainloop()
```