# Simple dialogbox multitasking

Tags: python, tkinter, simpledialog

How do ask a string and a integer question in a single simpledialogbox in tkinter without opening another simpledialogbox

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

simpledialog. askstring("name", "what is your name ")
Mainloop()
```

Comment: you can't. you have to create your own dialog box.

Comment: check the following link on how to create your own dialog box https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057672/correct-way-to-implement-a-custom-popup-tkinter-dialog-box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to implement a custom popup tkinter dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057672/correct-way-to-implement-a-custom-popup-tkinter-dialog-box)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Toplevel()` to create your own version of a `simpledialog`, something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.button1 = Button(self.root, text="Ok", command=self.drawtop)
        self.button1.pack()
    def drawtop(self):
        self.top = Toplevel(root)
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.top)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.top)
        self.button2 = Button(self.top, text="Done", command=self.printtop)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
    def printtop(self):
        print(self.entry1.get())
        print(self.entry2.get())
        self.top.destroy()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```