# Tkinter messagedialog askyesno with a checkbox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, dialog

Is it possible to make a Tkinter yes/no messagebox with a checkbox, for something like 'Never ask me again'?

Or would I have to create another window, create my own `Label`s and `CheckButton`s, and basically create my own dialog?

Comment: You would probably have to create your own dialog. Just remember to use `tkinter.Toplevel` for your custom dialog, not `tkinter.Tk`.

Comment: you could use the [`Dialog`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.simpledialog) as a base class to create your own dialog but yes otherwise you will yourself need to create the structure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to implement a custom popup tkinter dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057672/correct-way-to-implement-a-custom-popup-tkinter-dialog-box)

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own dialog box then.

Here’s what you can do:

```py
from tkinter import *

def popup():
    popupWin = Toplevel()
    popupWin.title(“Continue?”)

    checkVariable = IntVar()
   
    lbl = Label(popupWin, text=“Continue?)
    lbl.pack()
   
    btn2 = Button(popupWin, text=“Yes”)
    btn2.pack()
   
    btn3 = Button(popupWin, text=“No”)
    btn3.pack()

    checkBox = Checkbutton(popupWin, text=“Don’t ask again”, variable=checkVariable)

root = Tk()

btn = Button(root, text=Message Box, command=popup)

root.mainloop()
```