# Why does closing a tkinter child window with `frame.quit` exit my application?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `tkinter` application with two windows: A `MainWindow` that is created on startup, and a `ChildWindow` which is opened after clicking a button.

The `ChildWindow` should close itself if the user presses a button. However, when I try calling `frame.quit`, it terminates the entire application instead.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ChildWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.top)
        self.frame.pack()
        # BUG: Clicking "Close" will fully exit application
        self.close_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Close", command=self.frame.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.about_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Open child window", command=self._open_child_window)
        self.about_button.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def _open_child_window(self):
        self.about_window = ChildWindow(self.master)

root = tk.Tk()
lf = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshots:

[image: MainWindow] [image: ChildWindow]

Why does `frame.quit` exit my application? How can I close the child window without exiting?

Comment: You're using the wrong method. Use `destroy` instead of `quit`.

Comment: I think this question should be the one that it is duplicate of now, as this is easier to understand.

Comment: Run `import tkinter as tk; r = tk.Tk(); help(r.quit);` and `import tkinter as tk; r = tk.Tk(); help(r.destroy);` to see the docstring of the methods.

Comment: @Nae It appears both questions should be marked as duplicates of [How do I close a tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/110923/3357935)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `quit` causes `mainloop` to exit. With no event loop running, there's nothing left to keep the main window alive.

If you want to close a child window, call the `destroy` method.

```
self.close_button = tk.Button(..., command=self.top.destroy)
```