# Unable to make a button (created using tkinter) quit automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've written a script using `tkinker` in `python`. When I run the script, it receives an input and print that to the console. It is working great.

What I wish to do is add any functionality to my existing script in such a way so that after filling in the `inputbox` when I press the `get` button, it will print the value in the console and quits automatically. Once again, my existing script is capable of printing values. I need to make that button quit as soon as the printing is done. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

callback = lambda : get_val(e.get())
get_val = lambda item: print(item)  #this extra function is for further usage

Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback).pack()

master.mainloop()
```

This is how the `inputbox` looks like:

[image]

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110923/how-do-i-close-a-tkinter-window

Comment: Don't use lambda. Use proper functions. It will make debugging much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Comment: How come your provided link contains any such material that may solve the issue described here @Nae? Please read the post and try to compare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify the `callback` function as:

```
def callback():
    get_val(e.get()) #Gets your stuff done
    master.destroy() #Breaks the TK() main loop
    exit() #Exits the python console
```

> Here,`master.destroy()` breaks the `master.mainloop()` loop and thus terminates the GUI and finally `exit()` makes it exit the python console.

Answer (score 3):

Maintaining your `lambda` syntax:

```
callback = lambda : (print(e.get()), master.destroy())
```

The key is to call `master.destroy()`.

Comment: Your solution works great as well If I take out `item` from your suggested function. Given plus one. I wish I could accept it as well. Thanks.