# Python tkinter - calling a button command in a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on functions within a class, and one of the issues I'm running into is adding a button that terminates the program. Here is the current code:

```
class ClassName():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def close_root(self, root):
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()

    def addExitButton(self, root):
        Button(root, text = 'Exit', width = 10, command = self.close_root).grid(row = 5, 
             column = 0)
```

Within the button arguments, I have tried `command = self.close_root(root)` But this gives me an error because you can't call a function if you want the button to do something (I forget the reason as to why this is). I have also tried

```
def close_root(self):
    self.destroy()
    self.quit()

def addExitButton(self, root):
    Button(..., command = self.close_root,...)
```

And this does not work either as the class doesn't have the attribute `destroy.` I'm not sure how to approach this after trying a few different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually access the `root`'s functions. So using `self.root.destory()` or `self.root.quit()` will work because your root object has those methods but your class does not.

You should also only use one of them, in this case, `destroy` is the best option I think. And you can probably just use that when creating the button. So replace the button callback (command) with `self.root.destory`.

More here on [how to close a Tkinter window here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110923/how-do-i-close-a-tkinter-window)

Comment: I ended up using one of the answers in the link that was provided: `command = lambda root=root:self.close_root(root)`. This allowed me to keep the original function `close_root()`. Thanks!