# How do I close a window using destroy() in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a cancel button when pushed would cancel a program.

```
class PayrollSummary:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Employee Payroll")
        btCancel = Button(frame1, text = "Cancel", command = self.processCancel)

    def processCancel(self):
        self.destroy()
```

this is the error message I get:

> AttributeError: 'PayrollSummary' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Comment: Can you show construction of class

Comment: Can we know what self is assigned to? Widget? Tk main window?

Comment: done! my bad there...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to destroy the tkinter GUI, you must call `destroy` on the root window. According to the error you received, you are not calling `destroy` on the root window. You are apparently calling it on some other object.

Answer (score 2):

self refers to the "PayrollSummary" instead of the tkinter dialog/window initialised with Tk().

See [How do I close a tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110923/how-do-i-close-a-tkinter-window)

Answer (score 0):

As you've not inherited Tk in your `class PayrollSummary` the self.destroy() will not work on an Object alone, it is a method of `Tk`.

If you want to use destroy the window either you have to inherit Tk

**For example:**

```
class PayrollSummary(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *ags, **kw):
        super(PayrollSummary, self).__init__(*ags, **kw)
        self.title("Employee Payroll")
        btCancel = Button(self, text = "Cancel", command = self.processCancel)
        btCancel.pack()

    def processCancel(self):
        self.destroy()
```

**Or if you don't want to inherit Tk**

```
class PayrollSummary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Employee Payroll")
        btCancel = Button(self.window, text = "Cancel", command = self.processCancel)
        btCancel.pack()

    def processCancel(self):
        self.window.destroy()
```