# python tkinter small programm doesnt close

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-idle, sys

my first small GUI made with tkinter on python3.9 IDLE doesn't close.
my code is:

```
import tkinter, sys

def ende():
    sys.exit(0)

window = tkinter.Tk()
anzeige = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Guten Tag")
knopf = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Ende", command = ende)
anzeige.pack()
knopf.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

a small GUI opens with a button "Ende" and when i click it nothing happens, even though i defined a function when clicking on it... why so? thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at this question, it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110923/how-do-i-close-a-tkinter-window

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your code is in `tktest.py`.  Run it in from a command line with `python tktest.py`.  The GUI appears.  Click `Ende` and the command line prompt reappears.

Run it again with `python -i tktest.py`.  The `-i` says "when the program stops, switch to interactive mode and give me a python '>>>' prompt so I can explore the state of the program".  Click `Ende` and a traceback for `SystemExit` appears, followed by a `>>>` prompt.  The GUI is still present, and you can enter `dir()` and other Python statements.  Click `Ende` again and this time python exits.  The command line prompt reappears.

When you run your code from an IDLE editor with F5, it imitates running with `-i`.  A restart line and the GUI appear.  When you click `Ende`, `>>>`  appears.  This is not 'nothing happens'.  IDLE suppresses the SystemExit traceback.  Hit `Ende` and another `>>>` prompt appears instead of IDLE exiting.  This is all by design for user convenience.

Clicking the title bar [X] will close the gui.  Another user already answered about a Close or Exit button.