# How can I close this tkinter window after pressing the OK button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created this tkinter dropdown window where I select an option. After I choose that I press Ok and the option gets printed. How can I close this tkinter window after pressing the 'Ok' button?

```
from tkinter import *

OPTIONS = [
"Physician 1",
"Physician 2",
"Physician 3"
]

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

def ok():
    physician_name=variable.get()
    print (physician_name)

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I close a tkinter window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110923/how-do-i-close-a-tkinter-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to include `master.destroy()` after printing:

```
from tkinter import *

OPTIONS = [
"Physician 1",
"Physician 2",
"Physician 3"
]

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

def ok():
    physician_name=variable.get()
    print (physician_name)
    master.destroy()

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes. this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean close the entire application? Call `master.destroy()` within the `ok` function.