# Tkinter python not terminating the program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter

global win1,win2, win3

def win1_open():
    global win1
    win1 = tkinter.Tk()
    win1.geometry('500x500')
    button_next = tkinter.Button(win1, text='Next', width=8, command=win2_open)
    button_next.place(x=100 * 2 + 80, y = 100)
    win1.mainloop()

def win2_open():
    global win2
    win2 = tkinter.Tk()
    win2.geometry('500x500')
    button_next = tkinter.Button(win2, text='Next', width=8, command=win3_open)
    button_next.place(x=100 * 2 + 80, y=100)
    win2.mainloop()

def win3_open():
    global win3
    win3 = tkinter.Tk()
    win3.geometry('500x500')
    button_exit = tkinter.Button(win3, text='Exit', width=8, command=exit_program)
    button_exit.place(x=100 * 2 + 80, y=100)
    win3.mainloop()

def exit_program():
    global win1, win2, win3
    win1.quit()
    win2.quit()
    win3.quit()

win1_open()
```

The third window has Exit button that I have used to terminate the program. It terminates the program but only after I click Exit button thrice. How to terminate the program on one button click?

Comment: win.destroy() is what you should be using

Comment: You should only have 1 `.mainloop()` in your code as it can handle the event loop for all `tk.Tk()` windows.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `quit()`, you should use `destory()`

```
def exit_program():
    global win1, win2, win3
    win1.destroy()
    win2.destroy()
    win3.destroy()
```

To learn more about the difference between these 2 function, you can refer to this:
[How do I close a tkinter Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110923/how-do-i-close-a-tkinter-window)

Answer (score 1):

Change the calls in `exit_program()` to `.destroy()` instead of `.quit()`

Also, it's not necessary to have more than one `.mainloop()` in your Tkinter program. One mainloop suffices.